# Confusion about ''la ha tomado con él'

Tags: phrase

I understand that the phrase

> La he tomado con alguien

is a colloquial phrase which means [to have it in for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-it-in-for) someone.

My question is: does **tomado** change to **tomada** depending on the subject?

For example, if the teacher has it in for me and the teacher is a woman, is it

> La profe la ha tomado conmigo

or

> La profe la ha tomada conmigo

Is it referring to me or for example the grudge she bears e.g. el rencor?

I am confused about this.

Comment: No, **he tomado** is the present perfect of tomar. You never change the past participle in the present perfect. It is not an adjective.

Comment: @Lambie en el español no existe el *present perfect*

Comment: The translation of present perfect into Spanish would pretérito perfecto compuesto.  Its uses are almost the same as in English. I have seen the movie; He visto la película. So, I repeat, the past participle does not change.

Comment: @Lambie No, no lo es. ‘He visto la película’ ~= ‘Vi la película’. El PPC tiene valor de *pretérito*, lo dice el nombre mismo. No tiene valor de *presente* como en el inglés, por lo tanto las reglas de uso son bien distintas que en el inglés. Y a lo que más se parece es al pretérito simple. Que es equivalente del *present perfect* es meramente un invento de quienes aman forzar las traducciones

Comment: @tac En inglés el *present perfect" no tiene valor de presente.  Lo que tiene es la frase tiene valor "at the time of speaking", y el valor de pasado, es solo eso, pasado, sin especificar. He visto la película: I have seen the movie. = He visto la película comparado a Vi la película, I saw the movie.

Comment: "What is the perfect tense in Spanish?
The Spanish perfect tense, also pretérito perfecto/pretérito perfecto compuesto de indicativo, is used for actions completed in the recent past that have a connection to the present." [just like the present perfect in English.]

This tense is similar to the English present perfect tense (have done, have asked, have seen…) and is conjugated with the auxiliary verb haber + participle. Example:
Esta mañana no he hecho los deberes. https://espanol.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses/preterito-perfecto

Comment: @Lambie A ver si entendemos un poquito mejor. Supongamos que es cierto lo que decís. Tomemos la frase 'Ayer he visto a Juan', la cual es completamente válida en castellano. Según tu teoría, la traducción corercta es 'Yesterday I have seen Juan'. Lo cual contradice la regla del inglés de que el presente perfecto no se puede usar con adverbios de pasado. Llegamos así a un absurdo. Por lo tanto, están lejos de ser equivalentes. Usando la mera razón me es suficiente; no necesito estar al tanto de lo que dice el 99% de los sitios en internet, que ya sé que es falso

Comment: @tac No, at times the translation would be simple past. I gave a few examples but **not every possible example**. Ayer he ido al supermercado sería erróneo.=Wikipedia https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pret%C3%A9rito_perfecto_compuesto#:~:text=El%20pret%C3%A9rito%20perfecto%20compuesto%20se,ha%20entrado%20por%20la%20ventana. ayer ya terminó, pero se puede decir: Hoy or Esta semana he visto a Juan, porque el hoy o semana no se terminaran todavia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

- La he tomad**o** con él.

or, in River Plate dialect:

- Me la he tomad**o** con él. (More colloquial: Me la he agarrad**o** con él.)

we use "tomado" because the verb is in a perfect tense and in the ACTIVE voice. In perfect tenses, the past participle is invariable and does not have to agree with anything.

"la" refers to the situation, or perhaps the emotion (anger).

Objects do not have to agree with the participle:

- **La** he vist**o**.
- **Los** he ayudad**o**.

Instead, in the PASSIVE voice the participle will agree in gender and number with the subject, e.g.

- La ciudad ha sido tomad**a**.

Comment: El perfecto ("me la he agarrado") suena más a como lo diría un santiagueño que un porteño.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión no depende de ninguno de los actores. Tanto **"la"** como **"tomado"** se expresan tal cual.

**La ha tomado con él (ella, nosotros, contigo, conmigo...)** se puede considerar la contracción de una expresión mas larga. Ej.

```
- Pues la Madre Tornera me ha dicho que habéis quebrantado el ayuno 
  y que os ha visto coger de la despensa una tajada de jamón.
- ¡No me extraña que os lo diga porque la Madre Tornera la ha tomado conmigo!  
- ¿La tajada?
- No, que me ha tomado manía.

(Ruperto Chapi, 1893)
```

En el fragmento, se usa un juego de palabras y hace evidente que la parte de **"la ha tomado conmigo"** ya era de uso común y se esperaba que el lector la comprendiera. El autor usa la palabra manía como remate pero caben muchas opciones como *animosidad*, *antipatía*, *ojeriza*, *inquina*, *tirria*, *saña* y muchas otras. No es necesario especificar qué se ha tomado porque el interlocutor entiende que es algún tipo de sentimiento de adversidad.

También se puede usar la forma **la tomó con él**. En México tenemos frases un poco diferentes pero que son equivalentes como: **la agarró con él**, **la trae con él**, **la trae contra él**

Answer (score 0):

### No

Lo que has "tomado" es el hecho, no la persona que lo produce o ha producido

What you have "tomado" is the fact, not the person who produces it or has produced it.

For different pronouns only the tense of the present perfect changes:

> (Él/ella) La ha tomado con él/ella

> (Él/ella) La ha tomado con ellos/ellas

> (Ellos/ellas) La han tomado con él/ella

> (Ellos/ellas) La han tomado con ellos/ellas

Comment: Thanks. that answers it. it is a strange expression. tomar con ? what exactly are they talking about?

Comment: Tomar venganza, tomar revancha, son todos "hechos"

Comment: also, is it se la ha tomado con él for he has it in for him etc. how is it dealt with?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, Danielilo,. What I want to say is,how do I say ''he has it in for him'' or ''she has it in for her'', ''we have it in for them''etc. These construstions sometimes cause me difficulty and I wonder is it simple in this expression. I mean is it simply,''le ha tomado con ella'' to mean he has it in for her or is it''él la ha tomado con ella'' etc. tnx

Comment: Answer updated.-